# Linear Variable Differential Transformer Operation

Tags: voltage, circuit-analysis, current, transformer, inductance

[image]

Ok, so I am a bit unclear on how this device works. I know it converts the linear displacement to an electrical signal and the movable magnetic core acts as the linear displacement magnitude. My question is...

If I use this device as a feedback component that measures the current position of a load, how exactly does it do this?

Comment: Metrry. Didn't you just post the same thing and delete it?  Stop asking simple questions and read the book.  I already answered  this is a LVDT

Comment: Induced EMF depends on the type of core. If you move the core the induced emf will also vary. There are tons of videos and documents related to LVDT on the internet.

Comment: Sorry it was someone else using the same e-book https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/512789/inductive-position-transducer-sensing-devices/512798#512798

Comment: Do you understand how transformers work? If not then ditch this question and ask how transformers work but, before you do check out the search engine for this site and find the plethora of questions related to transformers and check them out. So, demonstrate your learning of a regular transformer and then we can begin to answer this question. If necessary add the demonstration to your question.